# Properly punctuating a sentence

Tags: american-english

English is my second language, so I am confused regarding this sentence and need some help.

“I told you that Janes can’t serve in that category within Tommy’s government not that I don’t like him.”

Should there be a comma after the government or is it okay to leave the sentence as it is?

Comment: There should be *at least* a comma.  More properly an em-dash, semicolon, or period.

Comment: A comma would completely change the sentence!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "not that I don't like him" to mean "It isn't that I don't like him (but...)" then you need to fairly firmly dissociate that from the first part of the sentence, and a dash is the usual way of doing that.

> I told you that Janes can’t serve in that category within Tommy’s government — not that I don’t like him.
>
> → Even though I rather like Janes, I told you he can't serve.

Using a comma indicates that you *actually did not say* that you didn't like him.

> I told you that Janes can’t serve in that category within Tommy’s government, not that I don’t like him.
>
> → What I said was he can't serve. I didn't say I didn't like him.